# Zend Studio 9 ignores "Space only" indentation on line break

Tags: php, symfony, zend-studio

I use Zend Studio 9 with the Symfony 2 plugin and set the codestyle also to Symfony.
The code style is set to use 4 spaces as indentation which sometimes isn't used.

For example, let's say, i write the following code:

```
$test = array();
```

When i now put the cursor between the brackets and press enter there are tabs in the spots marked with a "x":

```
$test = array(
xxxxxxxx);
```

How can i fix this problem?

I use the Symfony 2 plugin from "http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was a problem with the PDT dev build. I reinstalled Zend Studio without it and it now works.